# I have this Document in the database. How do I set a query in mongoose so that I can delete an object in the "cart" array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

> This is the post request that is supposed to delete the object in the "cart" array based on the product "id".

```
.post('/delete', async (req, res) => {
  if (await UserProfile.findOneAndDelete({ 'cart.id': req.body.id })) {   //This isn't woking.
     res.status(200).json({
        message: 'deleted',
     });
  } else
     res.json({
        message: 'failed',
     });
```

});

> Suppose I want to delete the object with the name : "BEER". How do I do that

[image: This is what the Document]

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this,

```
db.getCollection('Test').update(
    {"cart.id" : req.body.id },
    { $pull: { cart: { name: 'BEER' } } },
    false,
    true
);
```